# What is the difference between TYPE and DOMAIN in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering what is the difference between `CREATE TYPE` and `CREATE DOMAIN` in SQL? Anyone can help me on this subject?

Answer (score 10):

With `CREATE DOMAIN` you can create a subtype that is based on one existing type (adding constraints to it).

With `CREATE TYPE` you can create composite types or enum or others that they are structurally different to existing types.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are used for creating user-defined data types, but they have slightly different functionalities.

**CREATE DOMAIN**

- Used to define new data type with constraints or a subset of values from existing data type (simple, single-column data type with constraints).

> Example

```
CREATE DOMAIN positive_integer AS INTEGER
  CHECK (VALUE > 0);

CREATE DOMAIN email_address AS VARCHAR(255)
  CHECK (VALUE ~* '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$');
```

- Column created with CREATE DOMAIN is generally used to ensure that values adhere to specific constraints.

**CREATE TYPE**

- Used to define new data type that consist of one or more attributes.
- It allows you to create composite data types by combining the existing data types.

> Example

```
CREATE TYPE address_type AS (
  street VARCHAR(255),
  city VARCHAR(255),
  state VARCHAR(2),
  zip_code VARCHAR(10)
);
```

- Column created with CREATE TYPE can be used to store complex data that doesn't fit into primitive data types.